# Insert Failed first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user: []

Tags: apex

I am getting this error.
I know this question has been asked earlier too, i was wonderting if we can write any cutsom message  in error.csv when those error out.

Also, is it salesforce bug or my code bug as it is throwing ..

*Apex script unhandled trigger exception by user*

to my email id

```
try{
        List<Database.Saveresult> accountupdatedResults =  Database.update(updateAccMap.values(), true);
        }
        catch(Exception e){


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you are trying to share records with an inactive user or when you are assigning inactive user as the record owner .Make sure that you filter your query to include only active users with isActive=true .Certainly this is an error in apex and not an SFDC bug

For custom exception implement an exception class like below

```
public class InactiveUserException extends Exception {}
```

And then in your catch block use the below

```
try{
    update updateAccMap.values();
}catch(Exception e){
  throw new InactiveUserException(
           'Activated the user you are trying to assign the Account');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith..Could you please guide me further as i dont have control over user active or inactive..i have to assigned them to account owner,can i do something so that atleast in error.csv it will write that user should be active while i was using  Database.update(updateAccMap.values(), true);...do i have to put something in try catch so that it would not throw my exception on email

Comment: Yes if you can share the code ,I can help you

Comment: i am only updating account fields from some other object..and at last i am using..List<Database.Saveresult> accountupdatedResults =  Database.update(updateAccMap.values(), true);.....here is accountmap i have assigned some owners which are inactive and its throwing error

Comment: You can use try and catch and inside catch throw exception .You will create an exception class to write your own exception .Also please see how to click on edit of your question and attach code snippets with code editor

Comment: Thanks Mohith..I was not aware that we can attached code later too once question has been asked..i will check it

Comment: how that exception class would write error while dataloader error out that record in error.csv...

Comment: So when error happens via data loader the same exception is propagated if it's a trigger. Are you doing this in trigger?

Comment: Yes trigger is throwing error in csv.. but i want to write some custom message like please activate the user something..

Comment: How can i write overwrite standard error in error.csv with my custom message

Comment: Yes you can do that by extending exception class .Post your code

Comment: I have posted the code Mohith

Comment: Check here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex7_5.htm